# How to pull file from my Android device to a local folder on my PC

Tags: automation, appium-android, ddms

I'm trying to create a method that will pull a file from an Android device into a local path on my machine.

I'm using the pullFile method from com.android.ddmlib and I'm getting this error:

`02:45:59 E/ddms: Failed to open local file C:\Users\amiyahav\Desktop\PullFile for writing, Reason: java.io.FileNotFoundException: C:\Users\amiyahav\Desktop\PullFile (Access is denied)
02:45:59 E/Device: Error during Sync: Writing local file failed!`

This is my function:

```
public static void pullFile(@SuppressWarnings("rawtypes") AppiumDriver driver, String remote, String local) throws TimeoutException, FailureException, AdbCommandRejectedException, SyncException, IOException {
        AndroidDebugBridge.init(false);
        AndroidDebugBridge adb = AndroidDebugBridge.createBridge();

        String deviceUdid = (String) driver.getCapabilities().getCapability(MobileCapabilityType.UDID);

        long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        while (!adb.isConnected() || !adb.hasInitialDeviceList()) {
            if (System.currentTimeMillis() - startTime >= 20000)
                throw new TimeoutException("Error occurred while loading devices list");
            try {
                Thread.sleep(500);
            } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                throw new FailureException("Action execution interrupted",e);
            }
        }

        adb.getDevices()[0].pullFile(remote, local);
    }
```

This is the JUnit test:

```
@Test
    public void runPullFileAndroid() throws Exception {
        String remote = "/data/hw_init/product/media/Pre-loaded/Music/Dream_It_Possible.flac";
        String local = "C:\\Users\\amiyahav\\Desktop\\PullFile";
        AndroidDriver driver = runner.getDriver();
        try {
            ADBHelper.pullFile(driver, remote, local);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            throw new FailureException("Failed running ADB shell command",e);
        }

    }
```

Any help will be appreciated!

Comment: The error says access is denied trying to write to the folder on your PC. Apparently the account the code is running under doesn't have write-access to that folder.

Comment: Hi @KenWhite, Thnks for the quick reply :) I tried to grant this folder read/write permission, but it kep reverting it back.. Any idea why?